# asp.net - Can't process input from view

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

fairly newbie question here. I am creating a poll system in asp.net

In my view I have the following option:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Vote","Poll"))
{
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.option_Pal); 
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(m=>m.option_Pal, true)
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Vote!</button>
}
```

Then I receive said data in this method in my PollController:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Vote(Poll poll)
{
     if (Request.Form["m.option_Pal"] != null)
{
palResult.dailyVotesCounter++; //global counter where I store every vote
}
    return RedirectToAction("Result", "Poll");
}
```

palResult is initialized in the beginning of my PollController:

```
public class PollController : Controller
{DailyResult palResult = new DailyResult();
```

[...]

And finally:

```
public ActionResult Result()
{
    ViewBag.Message = "Pals : " + palResult.dailyVotesCounter;
    return View();
}
```

I have tried several ways but I can't get the `palResult.dailyVotesCounter` to increase when it's option is marked in the view. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you persisting `palResult` between requests?

Comment: What is palResult and where is it initialised?

Comment: palResult is an object initialized in the beginning of Poll Controller: DailyResult palResult = new DailyResult();

Comment: What happens when the user selects the radio button, then changes their mind and wants to un-select it! (radio buttons only work when you have at least 2). And `if (Request.Form["m.option_Pal"] != null)` is pointless since it will always be `null`

Answer (score 0):

The comment on the variable says it's a global counter, but MVC is stateless and as such you have to persist the value.  When the code does `RedirectToAction()` after incrementing the value, that value is lost (palResult object is destroyed) unless persisted in some mechanism like Session, cookie, passing it on the redirect as a querystring variable, etc.

So the easy way could have been:

```
return RedirectToAction("Result", "Poll", new { count = palResult.dailyVotesCounter });
```

However, that exposes the count to the user.